# how to have a CTA with max-width and height

Tags: html, css

I am currently searching a Call to action that has always the same width and length when you write a short of a bit longer text. This is the HTML that I am having right now. Can somebody help me out with this please?

```html
<table style="<tr">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;" align="center">
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td style="border: 2px solid #eee0d5; padding: 10px;" bgcolor="#eee0d5" align="center">


            <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@XXXXXXXX)=%%" title="" alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="%%=RedirectTo(@XXXXXXXX)=%%" style="text-decoration: none;">
              <font style="color: #000000; font-size: 16px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 600;">
                <strong style="color: #000000;"> THE CTA PLEASE</strong>
              </font>
            </a>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: What is the width and height you want to set for that button? I assume you want a fixed width and height. Right? Or how many text characters do you want to insert in that button? If you can tell that then I can calculate a fixed width and height according to that.

Comment: And also do you want only the text clickable like it is right now or you want the complete button clickable?

Comment: [font tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) is deprecated

Comment: *"...always the same width and length when you write a short of a bit longer text. "*  whahh?